# regex for TDIPerlRegEx case sensitive match

Tags: regex, delphi

How to create regex for TDIPerlRegEx, to make case sensitive match? I tried (?i-) but still I found words which start with small characters.

I want to create regex to find two words. **First word must start with first char uppercase** and the last two chars of the second word are 'th'.

```
TDIPerlRegEx.Create{$IFNDEF DI_No_RegEx_Component}(nil){$ENDIF};
  RegEx_Seek_1.MatchPattern := '(*UCP)(?m)(?i-)(?<=\W)[A-Z]\w{2,12}\W\w{3,12}th(?=\W)';
```

The result which I obtain includes first character lower case.

Example of text:
First, sell me your birthright.
The smell of your breath like apples.
"**Wisdom crieth** without".
Your earth as brass.
And **David cometh** in.
Wrath bringeth the punishments of the sword.

Now the items to be matched are 'Wisdom crieth' and 'David cometh'.

Comment: The way to disable case insensitive is `(?-i)`, not `(?i-)`

Comment: Thank you. Actually this is the solution.

Comment: Fine, I've put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, the way to disable case insensitive is `(?-i)`, not `(?i-)`

```
TDIPerlRegEx.Create{$IFNDEF DI_No_RegEx_Component}(nil){$ENDIF};
  RegEx_Seek_1.MatchPattern := '(*UCP)(?m)(?-i)(?<=\W)[A-Z]\w{2,12}\W\w{3,12}th(?=\W)';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Delphi regex syntax, but the following pattern seems to be working:

```
\b[A-Z]\S+\s\S*th\b
```

### Demo

But note that I actually get *four* matches:

```
Wisdom crieth
Your earth
David cometh
Wrath bringeth
```

From what I have read, Delphi's regex engine is built around PCRE, which is also what the demo uses.